# AngularJS: How to store the data from the service so I do not need to query again and again

Tags: angularjs, service

I have built a service to pass a variables among controllers. I have got in a variable (vm.organizations) all organizations and in vm.contacts all contacts in the Database in the listview.Html (under contactController).

```
//listview.html
<html ng-app="My-app">
<body ng-controller="contactsController">
<table class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name </th>
            <th>Company</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts>
            <td><a ui-sref="contact({Id: contact.id})" ng-click="vm.setCurrentContact(contact)">{{ contact.lastName}}, {{contact.firstName}} </a></td>
            <td><a ui-sref="organization({Id: contact.organizationId})"> {{contact.organization.organizationName}} </a></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have built a Service (dataservice.js) that get the data from the Database:

data service:

```
//dataService.js

(function () {

    angular.module('appContacts')
        .factory('dataService', ['$http', dataService]);

    function dataService($http) {

        return {
            getAllOrganizations: getAllOrganizations,
            getAllAvailableOrganizations: getAllAvailableOrganizations,
            getAllAvailableContacts: getAllAvailableContacts,
            getOrganizationById: getOrganizationById,
            GetContactById: GetContactById,
        };

        function getAllOrganizations() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/organizations'
            });
        }

        function getAllAvailableOrganizations() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/organizations'
            });
        }

        function getAllAvailableContacts() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/contacts'
            });
        }

        function getOrganizationById(id) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/organizations/{id}'
            });
        }

        function GetContactById(id) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/contacts/{id}'
            });
        }

    }
})();
```

And I call it from two controllers: contactsController.js and OrganizationsController.js

> My problem is that every time I navigate to another page, the service
>   has to get all the data that I already have from the Database which
>   ends in a performance problem. That data would not change inside a
>   session.

**Is there any way to store that info and be available from all controllers?**. I have read about local storage, but it is always used with `$scope` and as you see I am using Controller AS syntax (vm.contact instead `$scope.contact`)

Answer (score 0):

You can persist data in a service because services in AngularJS are singleton.They don't get destroyed when you navigate to different view.

```
(function () {

    angular.module('appContacts')
        .factory('dataService', ['$http', dataService]);

    function dataService($http) {
        var cachedOrganizations = [];
        return {
            getAllOrganizations: getAllOrganizations,
            getAllAvailableOrganizations: getAllAvailableOrganizations,
            getAllAvailableContacts: getAllAvailableContacts,
            getOrganizationById: getOrganizationById,
            GetContactById: GetContactById,
            getCachedOrginations: getCachedOrginations,
            setCachedOrginations: setCachedOrginations
        };

        function getAllOrganizations() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/organizations'
            });
        }

        function getCachedOrginations(){
           return cachedOrganizations; 
        }

        function setCachedOrginations(orginations){
           cachedOrganizations = orginations;
        }
    }
});
```

From your controller once you get data from backend, call `setCachedOrginations` to set data in service.

```
dataService.getAllOrganizations.then(function(data){
  dataService.setCachedOrginations(data);
},function(error){
})
```

Once you navigate to different `controller` you can get the previously stored data by call the service.

```
vm.orginations = dataService.getCachedOrginations();
```

**2nd option**

Use [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache) service

```
angular.module('dataCache')
  .factory('dataCache', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('data-cache');
  }]);
```

In your first Controller once you get data

```
 dataService.getAllOrganizations.then(function(data){
      // make sure you inject "dataCache" as a dependency
      dataCache.put("originations", data);
    },function(error){
    })
```

Once you go to second controller get the data from cache

```
vm.orginations = dataCache.put("originations");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But  how do I call the service without using $scope. I am using controller AS syntax

Comment: You can use `vm.orginations = dataService.getCachedOrginations();` $scope has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @RafaelMunoz I have updated my answer with an second option.. take a look

Comment: @RafaelMunoz Did that answer your question?

Comment: I am testing it. (the first version). But until now I did not see any improvement